# Find all the span styles with font size larger than the most common one via beautiful soup python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-table, font-size

I understand how to obtain the text from a specific `div` or `span` style  from this question: [How to find the most common span styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762692/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-most-appeared-common-span-style-in-beautifulsoup-pyth)

Now the difficulty is trying to find all the span styles with font sizes larger than the most common one?

I suspect I should use regular expressions, but first I need to extract the specific most common font size?

Also, how do you determine "larger than" when the condition is a string?

Comment: May be you should fetch all the styles in one list and iterate through it and store `font-size` of all style in one array(just number using regex) and you can find which number used most of the time and also you can find greater one.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:-

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re

    usedFontSize = [] #list of all font number used

    #Find all the span contains style 
    spans = soup.find_all('span',style=True)
    for span in spans:
        #print span['style']
        styleTag = span['style']
        fontSize = re.findall("font-size:(\d+)px",styleTag)
        usedFontSize.append(int(fontSize[0]))

    #Find most commanly used font size
    from collections import Counter
    count = Counter(usedFontSize)
    #Print list of all the font size with it's accurence.
    print count.most_common()
```

Answer (score -1):

To find all the span styles with font sizes **larger than the most common span style** using BeautifulSoup, you need to parse each CSS style that has been returned.

Parsing CSS is better done using a library such as [`cssutils`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssutils/). This would then let you access the `fontSize` attribute directly.

This would have a value such as `12px` which does not naturally sort correctly. To get around this, you could use a library such as [`natsort`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort).

So, first parse each of the styles into css objects. At the same time keep a list of all the soup for each span, along with the parsed CSS for the style.

Now use the `fontSize` attribute as the key for sorting with natsort. This would give you a correctly sorted list of styles according to their font size, largest first (by using `reverse=True`). `takewhile()` is then used to create a list of all entries in the list up to the point where the size matches the most common one resulting in a list of entries larger than the most common one.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile    
import cssutils
import natsort

html = """
    <span style="font-family: ArialMT; font-size:12px">1</span>
    <span style="font-family: ArialMT; font-size:14px">2</span>
    <span style="font-family: ArialMT; font-size:1px">3</span>
    <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size:12px">4</span>
    <span style="font-family: ArialMT; font-size:18px">5</span>
    <span style="font-family: ArialMT; font-size:15px">6</span>
    <span style="font-family: ArialMT; font-size:12px">7</span>
    """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")    
style_counts = Counter()
parsed_css_style = []       # Holds list of tuples (css_style, span)

for span in soup.find_all('span', style=True):
    style_counts[span['style']] += 1
    parsed_css_style.append((cssutils.parseStyle(span['style']), span))

most_common_style = style_counts.most_common(1)[0][0]
most_common_css_style = cssutils.parseStyle(most_common_style)
css_styles = natsort.natsorted(parsed_css_style, key=lambda x: x[0].fontSize, reverse=True)

print "Styles larger than most common font size of {} are:".format(most_common_css_style.fontSize)

for css_style, span in takewhile(lambda x: x[0].fontSize != most_common_css_style.fontSize, css_styles):
    print "  Font size: {:5}  Text: {}".format(css_style.fontSize, span.text)
```

In the example shown, the most commonly used font size is `12px`, so there are 3 other entries larger than this as follows:

```
Styles larger than most common font size of 12px are:
  Font size: 18px   Text: 5
  Font size: 15px   Text: 6
  Font size: 14px   Text: 2
```

To install you will probably need:

```
pip install natsort
pip install cssutils
```

Note, this does assume the font sizes used are consistent on your website, it is not able to compare different font metrics, only the numerical value.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm still testing it, because I need to use the font-size information back to the soup function to capture the content. Just a tiny question first, why != gives larger than? It should be not equal to? btw, no idea why someone clicked on not helpful.....

Comment: The list at that point is already sorted with largest to smallest, so the `takewhile` is used to read entries out of the full list until it matches the `12px` entry.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I've tried to bring back the font size back to the soup row.get function using regular expression, but it gave this error: AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Sorry,  not near a PC for a few days now. If you need the associated soup for a given entry, it just needs to be stored at the same time as getting the stykes. I will update it when I get a chance.

Comment: I have updated the script to give you access to the `soup` for each of the span entries.